# The import io.kubernetes.client.extended cannot be resolved

Tags: java, maven, kubernetes, import

The Kubernetes extended client import cannot be resolved (version 18.0.0). I am using java version "17.0.6" and Maven .These are the dependencies. I tried clean and rebuild the project but still same error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Pom.xml

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.kubernetes</groupId>
        <artifactId>client-java</artifactId>
        <version>18.0.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.kubernetes</groupId>
        <artifactId>client-java-extended</artifactId>
        <version>18.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have these dependencies only in `dependencyManagement` section, that's not enough. You have to have it in `dependencies` also.

The pom.xml should look like something similar to the following.

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">  
    
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>  

    ...
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.kubernetes</groupId>
                <artifactId>client-java</artifactId>
                <version>18.0.0</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.kubernetes</groupId>
                <artifactId>client-java-extended</artifactId>
                <version>18.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>  
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.kubernetes</groupId>
            <artifactId>client-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.kubernetes</groupId>
            <artifactId>client-java-extended</artifactId>
        </dependency>  
        ...
    </dependencies>  
</project>
```

In the `dependencies` section, you should only have the `groupId` and `artifactId` since the scope and the version are defined in dependency management.

Comment: Thanks for your time. but I modified the pom.xml and i still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to import kubernetes extended client libraries because of the compatibility issues, Check this [versioning and compatibility](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/wiki/2.-Versioning-and-Compatibility) page for information.

Here you need to consider the version of java, kubernetes extended client for java and kubernetes version. If you are using Java version 17.0.6 then your kubernetes extended client version should be 17.0.0 and kubernetes version should be 1.25.

You either need to make modifications based on your kubernetes version or based on your java version. So, upgrade or downgrade your software versions as per your requirement in order to meet the compatibility requirements, it will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your time. but I changed kubernetes extended client version to 17.0.0 ,I am using kubernetes version 1.25 and Java 17.0.6 and i still have the same problem.